# "Unhandled exception (KernelBase.dll) " error in CvAcc function using visual studio 2010 and opencv 2.2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with OpenCV 2.2 and I am trying to use the function CvAcc(img1,img2) that takes 2 images and sum them.

The Code is

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include<opencv/cvaux.h>
#include<opencv/highgui.h>
#include<opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
void main()
{
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
cvNamedWindow("Image", 1);


IplImage* sum= cvCreateImage( cvSize(640,480), 32, 1); 
    IplImage* mean= cvCreateImage( cvSize(640,480), 8, 1); 
    IplImage* img;

    img= cvLoadImage("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Open CV Images/img1.jpg"); 
    cvAcc( img, sum); 
    img= cvLoadImage("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Open CV Images/img2.jpg"); 
    cvAcc( img, sum); 


   cvConvertScale( sum, mean, 1.0/2,0); 
   cvShowImage("Image",mean);
   cvWaitKey(0);

   cvDestroyWindow("Image");

}
```

But an error occurs (Unhandled Exception) which is

```
    Unhandled exception at 0x000007fefdfc9e5d (KernelBase.dll) in tagroba.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002beef0..
```

So anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First you should be sure that your images are loaded succesfully by showing it on the screen. You can use cvShowImage method for that. If you can not show image after loading, probably the problem is space characters in your image paths.